# Deploying maven project to tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, maven-3

I have some problems with my maven project in Eclipse (webapp archetype). I wrote a simple appliaction with a single .jsp and a servlet. .jsp pages work fine but accessing a servlet results in a Class not found exception.
I think the problem is that maven (and also eclipse) deploys the servlet class as Servlet.java and not Servlet.class (in the wtpwebapps > .. > WEB_INF > classes >> etc. ).

The same code written as a Dynamic Web Application works fine because servlet is deployed by Eclipse with a .class extension.

I would like to stick with a Maven project so could you give me any hint on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault. I put my source code into src/main/resources and not src/main/java - thats why it wasn't compiled.

I would still like to know why maven doesn't deploy the application to wtpwebapps but the main issue is fixed now, thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat supplies servlet.jar. You need to put it in your pom.xml as `<scope>provided</scope>`.

That being said, Eclipse/Maven should not deploy servlet as a Java class file. It is a whole library provided by Tomcat which should NOT be compiled to a single class. You absolutely cannot have 2 servlet-api or servlet.jars in your packaged *.war file (the lib folder under webapps).

Also, it would probably help noting which ClassNotFoundException is being thrown. What class is missing? Because that sounds like your JSP version is referencing a class that isn't in the automatically deployed servlet-api jar Tomcat7 offers (3.0).

Comment: I mean that my class is deployed as .java (SimpleServlet.java and not SimpleServlet.class). The root cause it: ClassNotFoundException: com.webapp.simpleservlet.SimpleServlet.
Dynamic web app deploys similarly in the wptwebapps folder but there is a SimpleServlet.class in the classes folder and not .java.

Comment: btw: Eclipse deploys both project to wptwebapp directory, running mvn tomcat7:deploy puts it somewhere else - can I change it to wptwebapps too?

Comment: Why do you deploy using maven? Running a Tomcat through Eclipse and having set up the project as a Maven project in Eclipse through `mvn eclipse:eclipse`will automatically allow you to deploy it on Tomcat through Eclipse. If you start the Tomcat up in Eclipse, it will automatically compile and deploy the project.

Comment: Yes, thats what I do, but I was just curious why "mvn tomcat7:deploy" doesnt work in the same way as Eclipse.

Comment: Try to edit your original question and provide more information (and screenshots) regarding your setup. At this point, I can't say why these 2 behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `mvn tomcat7:deploy` then maven is searching for a running tomcat server as configured within the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <username>USERNAME</username>
        <password>PASSWORD</password>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <path>/training</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As you can see in the url the *manager* application is called for deployment (manager application is installed per default within a tomcat, but **NOT** within a tomcat within eclipse because eclipse uses it's own tomcat-webapp-folder (wptwebapp)).

Anyway, if you want to use this kind of deployment outside of eclipse, you have to create a user within the *tomcat-users.xml* with the roles `manager-gui` and `manager-script`.

Comment: Oh alright, I understand it now, thank you very much for clarification :)

Comment: By the way - if you want to commit the pom within an open repository (like GitHub) and don't want your username and password for your local TomcatServer within the pom.xml, you can exclude that into the maven settings.xml of your user directory (servers->server->id(TomcatServer),username,password). That way, you don't have to set username and password within the pom, but the server-entry has to match the server-id within the settings.xml so that Maven can combine these information for you. ;-)